# Canopy / iPython Notebook Image Issue

Tags: enthought

I've installed Enthought Canopy 1.3.0.1715 on Max OSX 10.9.2, and updated all packages.  All seems to have gone well until trying to create a new iPython notebook.  When the notebook opens, none of the buttons for the notebook contain any images (just small 'x''s).  II believe this problem is causing other issues in notebooks, but I'd like to get this one fixed first.  Has anyone seen this and have a solution / idea? FYI, This works fine starting notebook from the terminal, just not as how Canopy is hosting the notebook.